# Kubernetes - Networking inside cluster -

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing

I am trying to understand Kubernetes networking and came across the following snippet...in GKE network documentation...[GKE - Networking](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview#limit-connectivity). This says...

`Kubernetes manages connectivity among Pods and Services using the kube-proxy component, which runs on each node. kube-proxy, which is not an in-line proxy, but an egress-based load-balancing controller, watches the Kubernetes API server and continually maps the ClusterIP to healthy Pods by adding and removing destination NAT (DNAT) rules to the node's iptables subsystem. When a container running in a Pod sends traffic to a Service's ClusterIP, the node selects a Pod at random and routes the traffic to that Pod.`

I have two questions on this...

1. Assume there are 5 nodes out of which 3 nodes are part of service. Now one of the pod (from node that is not part of service) wants to communicate with service...   It finds service by FQDN of service..  Does the kube-proxy with in this node send traffic to one of the pod that is part of service ?
2. Also, it says kube-proxy load balances the traffic across the full set of pods...  how is that done ? If there is one single node that takes of traffic routing, it understand which one is the next node/pod to get traffic.. but Service picks nodes(with in a service) randomly right ?

Can someone please clarify ? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain the 2 question differently ? Sorry, I couldn't understand completely

Answer (score 3):

Please find the answers for your questions:

**1) Does the kube-proxy with in this node send traffic to one of the pod that is part of service ?**

**Yes**, `kube-proxy` will route the traffic to the correct pod(s). Each node in the cluster will have kube-proxy and each kube-proxy will write the `iptable` rules to **redirect the traffic to pods when serviceIP is used**.

**2) Lets take this example:**

We have 4 node cluster and two applications running with 2 replicas.

```
node1 -> application1_pod1
node2 -> application1_pod2
node3 -> application2_pod1
node4 -> application2_pod2 
(all 4 pods are running in different node)
```

Now application1 wants to talk to application2 using application2's service name.

```
1. application1_pod1 may talk to application2_pod1
1.1 (once this is done, node1 iptables will route next traffic to application2_pod2)
2. application1_pod2 may talk to application2_pod1 (as the iptables of node2 is not aware of previous traffic in node1)
2.1 (once this is done, node2 iptables will route next traffic to application2_pod2)
3. application1_pod1 will talk to application2_pod2 (because of 1.1)
4. application1_pod2 will talk to application2_pod2 (because of 2.1)
```

So at the end of step 2, *traffic to application2_pod1 is 100% and traffic to application2_pod2 is 0%*.
At the end of step 4, *traffic to application2_pod2 is 50% and traffic to application2_pod2 is 50%*.

**So it is strictly not round-robin, but eventually round-robin.**

**How service IP is converted to podIP ?**

ServiceIP is **virtualIP**. PodIP is basically containerIP (associated with some running process). ServiceIP points to PodIPs in round-robin.

kube-proxy will write iptable rules like below in each node: (lets say there are 3 pods)

```
When destination is equal to serviceIP, then route to 

- PodIP1 with 33% probability, 
- PodIP2 with 33% probability and
- PodIP3 with 34% probability
```

In order to achieve this, kube-proxy will listen to service(basically endpoints) creation and updates from API server.

Comment: Thank you Dinesh for  your help. I have been struggling to understand the flow..  when load balancer gets it, it sends to node and kube-proxy in that node sends it to any of the pod that is part of service. I want to know how kube-proxy get ip tables( mostly from API server ) ? How is the service ip leveraged here etc.  Can you please explain or point me to some document that can help me?

Comment: I added more details about serviceIP to podIP convertion

Answer (score 2):

Check this section of [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies)

kube-proxy runs in 3 different proxy mode:

1. User space proxy mode
2. iptables proxy mode
3. IPVS proxy mode

The implementation detail are different, but generally speaking, kube-proxy manages connections to Services and Endpoints. And like a proxy should, it can redirect traffics not belong to its node to correct ones.

So...

1) Yes

2) The doc you refer to is specifically for GKE. If you check k8s official doc, you will find only `kube-proxy in iptables mode chooses a backend at random.`, other mode will either use round-robin or user specified method to dispatch traffics.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree with you on 2, GKE uses iptables mode and so selects node at random but my question is.. how does load balance happen ? For example... I have 3 nodes, node 1 gets traffic now how does kube-proxy decides which pod should get traffic..?If there is one single node that manages traffic it has idea on whats going on, but in this context any node in the cluster may be picked up, how will a random node route traffic to a specific pod, so the load gets balanced ?

Comment: Let's take an example of having a service of 3 pods, 1 pod on node A, 2 pods on node B. You are asking if a traffic comes in and nodes are selected randomly (presumable evenly), it will not be balanced, right?

Comment: The thing is, service doesn't choose node randomly, it is **backend** was chosen randomly. And both node will have 3 entries of service-backend mapping in their own iptables. So it's no problem for traffics to be distributed evenly.

Comment: Ken, thank you. Created a diagram for better understanding... [link](https://imgur.com/WktqL4d).   <br/> If you see this image, node3 which has pod, is not part of service but part of cluster. Load balancer sends traffic to any of the node in the cluster ( not only nodes that are part of service).  Thinking if any node in cluster randomly gets traffic and kube-proxy gets the pods ips for service from API server and route the traffic....  how can that be load balanced ?  Does the API server when returning the endpoints for service to kube-proxy tell which pod should get traffic ?

Comment: A load balancer knows its services, so traffic should be directed to either node 1 or node 2. Then kube-proxy can distribute traffic evenly.

Comment: That's what I thought... but the following text in [gke documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/network-overview) says it different....  `The load balancer is not aware of which nodes in the cluster are running Pods for its Service. Instead, it balances traffic across all nodes in the cluster, even those not running a relevant Pod`... This is what has confused me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215596/discussion-between-deals-my-and-ken-chen).